# Grammar in Titles

Tags: grammar

Is it acceptable to have fragments as titles? Note the example below:

*Cars that Run on Air*

It is the title to a manual on hybrid cars. Is this example proper English or should I avoid fragments?

Comment: Walk into any library or bookstore, or log onto Amazon or Barnes & Noble and look at the first 20 titles you see. What does that tell you? Is *Introduction to Geometry* a complete sentence? Is it "proper English"? You understood it, right?

Comment: I did, thanks @Robusto. Sorry if you found this question sillly. Just wanted to make sure the register is appropriate, or "well-written" English.

Comment: Don't worry too much about that. Most native speakers don't.

Comment: @M-b: Not silly. I just wanted to impress upon you in a graphic way that this issue really doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I'm having real trouble coming up with the title of anything that actually *is* a complete sentence.

Comment: Why would you think there is something wrong with utterances which are not complete sentences with a tensed verb and a subject to accompany it? That's like saying you can't label a picture "my favorite kitty".  No sense to it.

Comment: Titles which are sentences: Their Eyes Were Watching God, It Follows, Mr Smith Goes To Washington, and Malone Dies, but it's definitely rare.